# How to show $P−λI$ is invertible for every $λ≠0,1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that for the projection $P$, $P−λI$  is invertible for every $λ≠0,1$.

The eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$ and $1$ and to determine the spectrum of $P$, I am trying to show that $P−λI$  is invertible, for $λ≠0,1$. Can someone help me with this? I am not sure how to show this invertibility. Thanks!

Comment: $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $P$ if and only if $P-\lambda I$ is not invertible. Since $P$ has only $0$ and $1$ as eigenvalue, then $P-\lambda I$ is invertible for all $\lambda \neq 0,1$.

Comment: We can show that the eigenvalues of $P-\lambda I$ are $-\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$. Thus, the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Are you asking about the finite-dimensional case or about general Hilbert spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to verify that for all $\lambda\ne 0,1$, one has
$$
  (\lambda I-P)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-P)+\frac{1}{(\lambda-1)}P\right)
   \\ = (\lambda(I-P)+(\lambda-1)P)\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-P)+\frac{1}{\lambda-1}P\right) \\
      = (I-P)+P=I.
$$
So $\lambda I-P$ is invertible for $\lambda\ne 0,1$, with
$$
         (\lambda I-P)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}(I-P)+\frac{1}{\lambda-1}P.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha=\frac1\lambda$ and consider instead $\alpha P-I$. Then we have
$$(\alpha P-I)(\beta P-I)=(\alpha\beta-\alpha-\beta)P+I$$
which equals to $I$ if it happens that $\alpha\beta=\alpha+\beta$, which occurs exactly when $\beta=\frac\alpha{\alpha-1}$, so since $\alpha\ne 1$, $\alpha P-I$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle a=\frac1{\lambda(1-\lambda)}$ and $b=-1/\lambda$, then
$$
  (P-\lambda I)(aP+bI)=I.
  \tag 1
  $$

---

As I suggested in a comment below a deleted question by the OP,  this can be easily  deduced by solving equation (1) in the
unknowns $a$ and $b$.